# SilverStripe CMS, Dropdown Field search by title or another match?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Hi I would like to get a search either by title or by product code in this use case, but the `map('ID', 'Title')` method does not expect an array to the second parameter, how could I get it?

```php
/* original snippet */
DropdownField::create(
    'ProductID',
    'Prodotto',
    Product::get()->sort('Title', 'ASC')->map('ID', 'Title')
)->setEmptyString('-- Seleziona --');

/* dummy sample snippet */
DropdownField::create(
    'ProductID',
    'Prodotto',
    Product::get()->sort('Title', 'ASC')->map('ID', ['Code','Title'])
)->setEmptyString('-- Seleziona --');
```

I took a look at the API, unfortunately I couldn't find a method that satisfies this for the DropdownField.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question asks for a search but your code is generating a string for the DropDownField.

If you want more advanced labels for the Dropdown you'd need a helper method on the Product DataObject like

```
public function getCodeAndTitleFormatted() 
{
    return $this->Code . ': ' . $this->Title;
}
```

Then you use this method in your `->map()` statement to create your DropDownField like:

```
DropdownField::create(
    'ProductID',
    'Prodotto',
    Product::get()->sort('Title', 'ASC')->map('ID', 'getCodeAndTitleFormatted')
)->setEmptyString('-- Seleziona --');
```